Find the mth largest element
Given an array of n integers, the values in array are 1 to n in any order.
Given another integer m as input.
Now pick the first m items from array (a sub-array of above array) and find the mth largest element from this sub-array.
Next pick the first m+1 items from array and find the mth largest element from this sub-array
so on.. till sub-array holds all n items.
Example:
n = 4
arr = [4,2,1,3]
m = 2

Result:
[2,2,3]

Explanation:
a) m items = [4,2] , mth largest = 2nd largest = 2
b) m+1 items = [4,2,1], 2nd largest = 2
c) m+2 items = [4,2,1,3], 2nd largest = 3

so result is [2,2,3]

This is my code:
static List<Integer> solve(List<Integer> arr, int m) {
   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
   int n = arr.size();
   for(int i=m; i<=n; i++) {
    List<Integer> sub = arr.subList(0, i);
    Collections.sort(sub, Collections.reverseOrder());
    result.add(sub.get(m-1));
   }
   return result;
}

I want to optimize it so it takes less time to run, what is the correct approach to solve this?

In your "now pick..." step you say "Now pick m items from array" -- do you mean "Now pick the first m items," and that each successively larger subarray is also the first i elements for some i?

@Dave, yes first m items, then first m+1 items. I updated my post now.

If this is LeetCode or some other coding challange, please post the link.

Linear:

create a length n+1 bitvector and set the m bits corresponding to the first m integers. keep track of the smallest integer you've seen so far and set i to this value, and put i in your answer array.

To process an integer k:

2a) If k < i, ignore it.
2b) if k > i, set the k'th bit of your bitvector, and increment i until it reaches another set bit.
2c) append i to your answer.



This is linear because we increment at most n times across the algorithm.
Example:
n = 4
arr = [4,2,1,3]
m = 2

step, bitvector, answer, notes
0     10100      [2]     The final 0 in 10100 is the 0th index, which we ignore.
1     10100      [2, 2]     1 is smaller than 2, so it doesn't affect our answer.
2     11100      [2, 2, 3]  3 is bigger than 2, so we increment i until we hit another set bit, in this case 3.

Ruby Code: This function takes in n and m, generates a shuffled array of 1-n, and then uses my approach to get the output you're looking for in linear time.

    def f(n, m)
      # We'll use two indices for this:
      #   i: we use i to parse the whole array
      #   j: we use j for the mth largest element
      
      # create an array by shuffling 1-n
      arr = 1.upto(n).to_a.shuffle!
      # initialize variables
      ans = []
      bitvec = 0
      j = arr[0]
      
      # parse the first m elts of arr
      0.upto(m-1) do |i|
        elt = arr[i]
        bitvec |= 1 << elt  # set the bit that matches the elt
        if elt < j
          j = elt
        end
      end
      ans.append(j)
      
      # parse the rest of the array
      m.upto(n-1) do |i|
        elt = arr[i]
        if elt > j
          # set the corresponding bit
          bitvec |= 1 << elt
          
          # increment j until we encounter the next set bit
          loop do
            # increment j
            j += 1
    
            # if the new j'th bit is set
            break if bitvec & 1 << j > 0
          end 
        end
        ans.append(j)
      end
      
      return "input arr = #{arr.to_s}; ans = #{ans.to_s}"
    end


Here's some sample output:
> f(10,4)
=> "input arr = [3, 2, 8, 5, 1, 10, 7, 9, 6, 4]; ans = [2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7]"
> f(10,4)
=> "input arr = [3, 8, 4, 10, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5]; ans = [3, 3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7]"
> f(10,4)
=> "input arr = [8, 2, 7, 9, 3, 10, 1, 6, 4, 5]; ans = [2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]"
> f(10,4)
=> "input arr = [8, 4, 6, 3, 1, 9, 10, 2, 5, 7]; ans = [3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7]"
> f(10,4)
=> "input arr = [3, 9, 2, 7, 10, 4, 8, 1, 5, 6]; ans = [2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7]"


My answer is linear time and linear space, or more specifically, O(n) time and O(n) space.
We can get it down to O(n) time and O(m) space by using a set instead of a bitvector, and after initialization, only keeping the m largest elements in the set. Here's code to do that (in Ruby):

    def g(n, m, arr = nil)
      # We'll use two indices for this:
      #   i: we use i to parse the whole array
      #   j: we use j for the mth largest element
      
      # create an array by shuffling 1-n
      arr = 1.upto(n).to_a.shuffle! if arr.nil?
      # initialize variables
      ans = []
      s = Set.new()
      j = arr[0]
      
      # parse the first m elts of arr
      0.upto(m-1) do |i|
        elt = arr[i]
        s.add(elt)
        if elt < j
          j = elt
        end
      end
      ans.append(j)
      
      # parse the rest of the array
      m.upto(n-1) do |i|
        elt = arr[i]
        if elt > j
          # set the corresponding bit
          s.add(elt)
          s.delete(j)
          
          # increment j until we encounter the next set bit
          loop do
            # increment j
            j += 1
    
            # if the new j'th bit is set
            break if s.include?(j)
          end 
        end
        ans.append(j)
      end
      
      puts "input arr = #{arr.to_s}; ans = #{ans.to_s}"
    end
    
    def h(n, m)
      arr = 1.upto(n).to_a.shuffle!
      f(n, m, arr)
      g(n, m, arr)
    end



Trying to understand how did you get 10100 in step 0? For 4 you set (4+1=5)th bit and for 2 (2+1=3)rd bit and so on?

I am trying to understand this, create a length n+1 bitvector and set the m bits corresponding to the first m integers. so if n is 4 my bitvector is [0,0,0,0,0] with n+1 items. now how to do this set the m bits corresponding to the first m integers to make it 10100,

@SomeDude I added an example at the end showing me setting the bit at index 4 and 2. The reason for the extra bit is just to avoid the hassle of shifting by 1 to account for the input array being 1-indexed.

I am still trying to understand, what is the example indicates in the end `> bv |= 1 << 4
=> 16

bv |= 1 << 2
=> 20
puts bv.to_s(2)`


@learner See the example I added to the end. The exact details may depend on your language. In Ruby, an integer can be used as a bitvector, and we can set the k'th bit by using "bitvector |= 1 << k". For step zero, we do this for each of the first m elements of the input array.

@learner That's language specific (Ruby). "bv |= 1 << 4" sets the bit at index 4. Ruby spits out the number in base 10 each time you do that, so it's displaying 16, but in binary that's 10000. The bv.to_s(2) shows the bitvector in base 2.

Lets say your first number is Integer.MAX (2147483647) now 1 << Integer.MAX would be negative and next if you do -1 << 4 , it would be 0 now there are no set bits. What then?

@SomeDude I don't know Java. Are you saying there's no way in Java or its libraries to have a bitvector with more than Integer.MAX bits? If true, then my solution may not help the OP if his input arrays are that big.

@SomeDude An array of ints could function as a bitvector.

Thanks Dave, your answer is interesting to learn, I did't expect we can solve using bitvector for this question :). I am finally stuck at The final 0 in 10100 is the 0th index, which we ignore. what this notes indicates. Result at this point is 2 , what is the importance of 0th index here.

@learner Since your input array doesn't include a zero, I thought it was a bit cleaner to ignore the zeroth bit, vs having the zeroth bit correspond to '1' and the first bit to '2' and so on. Either way is fine.

@Dave ok may be I misunderstood by how you construct bitvector.

 increment i until it reaches another set bit. this should be implemented using a loop to find the next set bit right, so does this affect time complexity beyond linear

@learner yes to loop, but no to non-linear. Since the elts are 1-n, in total we'll never increment more than n times.

@learner I added working code & sample output; hopefully that clarifies things.

You can solve this in O(n log m) time by maintaining a binary heap that contains the m largest values in a running prefix. The m-th largest value is simply the smallest of those m values.
Here's a sample implementation in Python to demonstrate the algorithm:
import heapq

n = 4
arr = [4,2,1,3]
m = 2

heap = arr[0:m]
heapq.heapify(heap)
res = []
for i in range(m, n):
  # Invariant: heap contains the m largest values of arr[0:i] in min-heap order.
  # Therefore, heap[0] (the smallest of the m largest values) is the m'th largest value in arr[0:m].
  res.append(heap[0])
  heapq.heappushpop(heap, arr[i])
# At this point, heap contains the m largest values of arr. Add the final value to the result.
res.append(heap[0])

print(res)  # prints [2, 2, 3]

You can implement this in Java using PriorityQueue:
static List<Integer> solve(List<Integer> arr, int m) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int num : arr) {
        pq.add(num);
        if (pq.size() > m) pq.poll();
        if (pq.size() == m) res.add(pq.peek());
        
    }
    return res;
}

Which can be optimized for the common case where the m-th element doesn't change every iteration:
static List<Integer> solvePriorityQueue(List<Integer> list, int m) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(list.subList(0, m));
    Integer mth = pq.poll();
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(list.size() - m + 1);
    res.add(mth);
    // Invariants:
    //  - mth is the m-th largest element
    //  - pq contains the next (m - 1) larger elements
    for (Integer i : list.subList(m, list.size())) {
        if (i > mth) {
            pq.add(i);
            mth = pq.poll();
        }
      res.add(mth);
    }
    return res;
}


Here's a solution that keeps track of only the mth largest values encountered each time, sorted.  Whenever a larger value is encountered, it replaces the smallest value, and re-sorts those items.
static List<Integer> solve(List<Integer> list, int m) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> largest = list.subList(0, m).stream().sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    result.add(largest.getFirst());

    for (Integer element : list.subList(m, list.size())) {
        if (element <= largest.getFirst()) {
            result.add(largest.getFirst());
        } else {
            largest.set(0, element);
            largest.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
            result.add(largest.getFirst());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Sorting the sublist requires (at worst) O(m log (m)) operations for the first sort, and "far fewer than [that]" for each subsequent sort since the list is mostly sorted.  Adding and replacing the elements are all constant time operations.  So the overall time complexity is between than O(n) + O(m * (n - m) * log m) and O(n) + O((n - m) log m), and probably much closer to the latter.
This could be made even more efficient by using a collection type that is natively sorted and allows duplicates, such as a Guava SortedMultiset.
static List<Integer> solve(List<Integer> list, int m) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(m);
    SortedMultiset<Integer> largest = list.subList(0, m).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeMultiset::create));
    result.add(largest.firstEntry().getElement());

    for (Integer element : list.subList(m, list.size())) {
        Integer firstElement = largest.firstEntry().getElement();
        if (element <= firstElement) {
            result.add(firstElement);
        } else {
            largest.remove(firstElement);
            largest.add(element);
            result.add(largest.firstEntry().getElement());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Since TreeMultiset has similar characteristics to TreeSet, add and remove would each have time complexity of log(m).  Therefore, the overall time complexity is O(n log m).

What's the running time?

@Dave - Added time complexity to my answer

The solution in the first part has complexity O(n×m), not O(n log m); to see why, consider the case where m = n/2 and the list contains strictly increasing values.
The second solution is basically equivalent to the priority queue solution I proposed, except that TreeMultiset is slower than PriorityQueue by some constant factor.

@MaksVerver I agree that my second solution is basically equivalent to the priority queue solution, but how do you know that the TreeMultiset solution is slower than the PriorityQueue one?  I'm not saying it is (or isn't), but (without testing it), I don't see anything to indicate which would be faster.

@MaksVerver It's not the most finely tuned microbenchmark, but running both solutions locally against a large list (1,000,000 elements) and a fairly large m (50,000) has the TreeMultiset solution be noticeably faster than the PriorityQueue one: PriorityQueue: 124 ms TreeMultiset: 32 ms.

@M.Justin TreeSet is usually slower than PriorityQueue because it has a less efficient in-memory representation (an explicit tree of heap-allocated nodes vs a flat array that represents a complete binary tree implicitly). The performance difference you found comes from the if (element <= firstElement) optimization you use to avoid updating the set most of the time. You can do the same thing for the PriorityQueue and then you'll see the PriorityQueue based version is 2 or 3 times faster. Here is the code I used to benchmark: https://gist.github.com/maksverver/5abf52c8e4ba79857fa2646ea091bf60

Also a minor thing: new ArrayList<>(m) should be new ArrayList<>(list.size() - m + 1) if you want to preallocate capacity equal to the list's final size. I don't think this has a large performance impact though.

@MaksVerver In my implementation, I never resize the list and only keep the greatest m elements encountered so far in that list, so new ArrayList<>(m) should be correct.

@MaksVerver Thanks, that explains the speed difference you're claiming.  I see a speedup of a bit under 2x in my local benchmark as well: PriorityQueue solution: 114.9 ms TreeMultiset solution: 75.32 ms PriorityQueue solution (optimized): 46.80 ms

@M.Justin: it sounds like you're talking about the largest list, but the I'm talking about the result list, which will always contain n - m + 1 elements in the end, yet you initialize it to capacity m instead.
